# Storing Video files in Android

Tags: android, video

I am a newcomer to Android programming.
I have a couple of qs with respect to Android's handling of video data.

a) Is it possible for Android to password protect the captured video data (captured from your custom video app)  ?
b) I have heard that Android has a "mini" database on its own.So can we store the captured video inside the database ?.

Comment: Did you try cipherinputstream ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a) Is it possible for Android to password protect the captured video
>   data (captured from your custom video app) ?

You can encrypt data using [CipherInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html). An easier way is to just store the video in your app's internal storage. Users won't be able to get at it through other apps, since each app has its own internal storage with corresponding ID. This second method, however, is more about hiding files from casual inspection, since a root user can access it anyhow.

> b) I have heard that Android has a "mini" database on its own.So can
>   we store the captured video inside the database ?.

Android devices have a built-in SQLite database, but storing video data there (as binary) would result in horrible performance.  SQLite has little overhead compared to other database solutions, but that's not the same as **zero** overhead. I'm messing around with MediaPlayer at the moment, and I only use the SQLite database to store URIs of media files in the form of play lists.

Comment: Thanks for sharing info regarding CipherInputStream.

Comment: Also one quick question,say I encrypt the captured video from my app and store it in SD card.Anyone who can view the contents of that SD card will still not be able to see the video file but only the encrypted content ..am i right ?

Comment: You are right. You'd need the decryption cipher in order to restore the video file to a usable form.